# <select> has extra blank <option>'s and I have no idea why. please help me get them out

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

[This is the result of the code it has extra option tags no idea why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5AZJ.png)

I have no idea why It produces the extra option box.

Below is the result of the query. Correct number of rows correct response...

```
     ParentID   Parent
    1   Pipe
    2   Valve
    3   Control Valve
    4   Pump
    5   Chamber
    6   Meter
    7   Check
    8   Distribution Pipe
```

This is some php that makes the dropdown:

```
$qry = "select distinct ParentID, Parent from tbl
    where ChildID = '0' and Parent is not null";

$parentRslt = mysql_query($qry);

$count = mysql_num_rows($parentRslt);

$opt7 = null;

for($m=0;$m<$count;$m++)
    {
        $var = mysql_result($parentRslt,$m,'ParentID');
        $name = mysql_result($parentRslt,$m,'Parent');

        $var = trim($var);
        $name = trim($name);

        $opt7.="<option value='$var'>$m $name<option>";
    }


$form = "
    <form method='post'>

    Network Action: <input type='text' name='child' />  
    <select name='parentID'>
            $opt7
    </select>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' /></form>";

return $form;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close the `option` tag. Change

```
$opt7.="<option value='$var'>$m $name<option>";
```

to

```
$opt7.="<option value='$var'>$m $name</option>";
```

Comment: I cant believe I overlooked that. thanks so much Palacsint.